# Confused about the axis labels of ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm not really familiar wih ListDensityPlot and for example I have the following code

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[N[Sin[x]*Cos[y]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 2, 7}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, ColorFunction -> ColorData["SolarColors"]]
```

What is in the x and y axis? And why is the x axis numbered from 1 to 6 and not 0 to 5. The same for the y axis, why is it also numbered from 1 to 6 and not 2 to 7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `ListDensityPlot[Flatten[Table[{x,y,N[Sin[x]*Cos[y]]}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 2, 7}],1], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["SolarColors"]]` . You need to use a three column array for `ListDensityPlot`.

Comment: @Sumit beat me to it, except I'd use `Catenate` rather than the more `Flatten[..., 1]`.  You could also (less cleanly, IMO) use `DataRange->{{0,5},{2,7}}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short `ListDensityPlot` like other `ListPlot` variants uses the index of the value of the array for the axes ticks unless it is otherwise specified.

If you wanted it to plot with the coordinates you passed there are several ways. One way is to add the option `DataRange -> {{2, 7}, {0, 5}}` to `ListDensityPlot`. Note that with how you have constructed your table, your $y$ coordinate is on the $x$-axis.

An alternative way is to include the coords in the data with something like

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y, N[Sin[x]*Cos[y]]}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 2, 8}], 1]
```

or maintaining your axes:

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y, N[Sin[x]*Cos[y]]}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 2, 8}], 1]
```

You have to flatten the array in this case because of what `ListDensityPlot` is able to interpret.

**Edit:** It seems I was ninja'd by the comments.

Comment: "It seems I was ninja'd by the comments." - it's fine, answers trump comments. :)